Apple mail inline html
Trying to write an email using Gmail API to send an email containing some plain text and some inline html (serially)
draft_message = MIMEMultipart("mixed")

text_part = MIMEText("hey, this is text", "plain", "utf-8")
draft_message.attach(text_part)

html_part = MIMEText("<p>hey this is html</p>", "html", "utf-8")
draft_message.attach(html_part)

however the html is an attachment when viewed through Apple Mail (Gmail client it works as intended).
Any ideas how to fix this (have html inline) for Apple Mail?
I want to use 'mixed' here as I these two parts are independent, they are not text/html versions of each other so i don't want to use 'alternative'.
Does Apple Mail treat the html it as an attachment unless it is part of a multipart/alternative container with a plain text counterpart?
I have tried:

html_part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline')

